# Is levenshtein distance the best tool for the job when I know the proper spelling of a string and historical misspellings?

Tags: c#, sql, spell-checking, levenshtein-distance

I have two tables.

**Table A** has a single entry for each current employee, and contains the proper spelling of each user. There is only ever 80 employees at a given time, but the names themselves change periodically.

It looks a bit like this:

| FirstName | MiddleName | LastName | EmployeeID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John |  | Smith | 1234 |
| Michael | Doe | Tabler | 1235 |

I have another table, **Table B**, with millions of entries. This table is populated by users in the field entering in full names as they hear them in person.

| Name | DateEntered |
| --- | --- |
| JOHN SMITH | 20210701 |
| JONATHAN SMITH | 20210701 |
| MICHAEL DOE | 20210630 |
| MIKE DOE | 20210425 |
| JON R. SMITH | 20201231 |

To see what I'm up against, I ran a simple query attempting to view certain variations on names. Something like:

```
SELECT TOP 50 Name, COUNT(*) as hits 
FROM Table_B
WHERE Name like 'Jo%' and Name like '%Sm%' 
GROUP BY Name 
ORDER BY hits desc;
```

Which returns:

| Name | Hits |
| --- | --- |
| JOHN SMITH | 171 |
| JOHN R. SMITH | 98 |
| JONATHAN SMITH | 67 |
| JOHN R SMITH | 45 |
| JOHNSMITH | 35 |
| JOHN SMIHT | 12 |
| JOSIE SMULLET | 9 |
| JOHN DOE FOR BRAD SMATTEX | 1 |

And so on and so on, with as many variations as you can think of on a given name.

Quite simply, I need to be able to view future misspellings and properly associate it to a user.

Now, I've managed to get a C# project that can determine the levenshtein distance between strings, so this question isn't really about how to generate the distance itself, or even how to write the code that will solve my problem.

I'm more so wondering if I am using the right tool for the job by assuming that a levenshtein function is my secret key, or if I am creating an XY problem and should be investigating other avenues to solve this, or if I even have enough data in front of me to achieve the task at hand.

Comment: I would say you don't have enough data: certainly Levenshtein is not accurate enough to definitively associate values to each other, it can only give you a rough estimate

Answer (score 1):

It becomes a design choice, both in the schema and in the UI.

- Who will be managing the name `Alias` data?
- Is there a UX to clarify when a unique match cannot be made with certainty?
- how many different processes need to use the `Alias`?
- how often is the `Alias` lookup going to be used.?
- what level of certainty do you need, and how critical is the data?

If you want the users to be able to manage the known `Alias` or common misspelling, the by all means create a table (or array) that allows the users (or administrators) to manage the lookup.

It also comes down to the scenario. If you need this for frequent importing of data then you need a definitive source of data to match on to give you confidence that your process will work.

In this scenario, I would validate the input against the mapped `Alias` values for each name, if a unique name cannot be identified, fail the input until a unique result can be found, this forces either DBA, Admin or users to update the `Alias` list accordingly.

If this is very infrequent, then it might be simpler to manage this in a script that parses and modifies the input first, rather than building this into your schema. Then you or the DBA performing the input can manage the script when the list of employees changes, or a new misspelling appears.

> Be careful not to over-engineer solutions like this. Levenshtein is great to sort lists of users against a search argument to assist users to find someone, but due to internationalization, multiculturalism and general quirky choices of people out there, the number of names that clash or return false matches might not be acceptable.